# How can I account for package trace length in KiCAD?

Tags: pcb-design, kicad, trace

The documentation I got for the MCU provides "package trace length" (in micrometers) as well as "package trace delay" (in picoseconds). For example like this - 6535.15 um package trace length for M_DQ[18] trace with delay 44.47 ps. The MCU itself has rather a high number of high speed interfaces all of which suppose to be used according to the specifications (multiple SERDES lines, GbE, DDR3 etc).

Given this information, how can I easily account for it in my design if I am using KiCAD?

I know, I could use basic math and just keep track of each single trace on paper and add package length to ensure differential pairs are of matching length (in-pair and across pairs), but that seems like a headache. Is there any better option?

Comment: Are you sure these are not negligible relative to your overall design?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I would prefer to think those are negligible, but 1 - the hw design guide (for this series of MCU) provided by manufacturer stresses quite a lot on attention to diff.pair scewing and trace impedance matching, and 2 - the number vary quite a bit there with some high-speed differential pairs package traces differing by over 2mm (which is quite a lot IMO)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Hi, OP is working with high speed digital design, and the trace lengths are very crucial else the signal quality will degrade very quickly and such board are atleast 4 or 6 layers, doing revisions can get very expensive.

Comment: @AlexKey I personally use altium for high speed stuff(which has much better length matching features) but still I use excel for keeping track of the lengths.

Comment: @HemalChevli I’ve heard quite good feedback about Altium thus far. But I can’t even find where to get it. Official website refers to a bunch of resellers none of which are in my region.

Comment: @AlexKey try dropping them a mail, perhaps?. It is quite expensive, my company got it for about $8K plus they charge every year for sending updates.

Comment: @HemalChevli right. Judging from the price alone they don’t count on individuals there ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71810/discussion-between-hemal-chevli-and-alexkey).

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried this, but I found this inside the [documentation](http://docs.kicad-pcb.org/stable/en/pcbnew.pdf#page=11) of the footprint editor:

If you edit the pad properties a field shows up marked as "Pad to die length". I guess this is what you are looking for. So edit the package of the chip and adjust all the pads with the corresponding numbers from your datasheet.

[image: Pad Properties in KiCAD] picture taken from [here](http://kicad.txplore.com/index-p=111.html).

You might want to try that with two pads first before editing hundreds of them.

Comment: Great find. I've just imported library from Eagle, and have not even looked at editing options. There was nothing like that in Eagle. I will try and see how that works. Judging by the name should be it.

Comment: @AlexKey have you tried it out yet?

Comment: I have not yet, but I’ll update here as soon as I do.

Comment: @AlexKey any update on this?